# I need to pass multiple check boxes from jquery to php and GET is as an array in php

Tags: php, jquery

i need to pass a get variable via jquery, one of the form fields is a multiple check box. so i want to be able to pass it so that from php i can use GET and collect it then use IMPLODE to get such a value but its not working

JQUERY CODE HERE

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

                $.get('actionfilter.php', function(data){
                             $('.disFilter').html(data).fadeIn("2000"); 

                        });

          $("#FilterForm :input").change(function() {
          $(this).closest('form').data('changed', true);

                var FilterByOrder = $("#FilterByOrder").val();

                var location = $("#location").val();
                var sortFilter = $("#sortFilter").val();
                var Highlights = $("#Highlights").val();

                if (FilterByOrder == '' || location == '' || sortFilter == '' || Highlights == '') 
                {

                   $.get('actionfilter.php', function(data){
                             $('.disFilter').html(data).fadeIn("2000"); 

                        });
                }
                else
                {
                   $.get('actionfilter.php', {FilterByOrder: FilterByOrder, location: location, sortFilter: sortFilter, Highlights: Highlights}, function(data){
                             $('.disFilter').html(data).fadeIn("2000");

                        });
                }
    });
});
```

THE PHP VERSON

```
 <?php
if(isset($_GET['FilterByOrder'])){
  echo 'filter '. $FilterByOrder=$_GET['FilterByOrder'].'<br>';
  echo  'location '.$location=$_GET['location'].'<br>';
   echo 'sort '.$sortFilter=$_GET['sortFilter'].'<br>';
   echo 'highlits '.$Highlights=$_GET['Highlights'].'<br>';

   echo 'here is the one!';
}else
{
  echo'lets run it';
}

?>
```

THE HTML FORM FIELD

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Highlights[]" value="<?php echo $DisplayedHighlightID; ?>" id="Highlights">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var searchValue = $("#searchValue").val();
            $.get('actionfilter.php', {searchValue: searchValue}function(data){
                         $('.disFilter').html(data).fadeIn("2000"); 

                    });

      $("#FilterForm :input").change(function() {
      $(this).closest('form').data('changed', true);

          if($("#FilterByOrder").prop("checked") == true){
            var FilterByOrder = 'on';
          }
          else
          {
            var FilterByOrder = 'of';
           }

            var location = $("#location").val();
            var sortFilter = $("#sortFilter").val();

            /* declare an checkbox array */
            var HighlightsArrays = [];

            /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
            $(".Highlights:checked").each(function() {
                HighlightsArrays.push($(this).val());
            });
                /* we join the array separated by the comma */
                var selectedHighlights;
                selectedHighlights = HighlightsArrays.join(',') + ",";


            if (FilterByOrder == '' || location == '' || sortFilter == '' || Highlights == '') 
            {

               $.get('actionfilter.php', function(data){
                         $('.disFilter').html(data).fadeIn("2000"); 

                    });
            }
            else
            {
               $.get('actionfilter.php', {FilterByOrder: FilterByOrder, location: location, sortFilter: sortFilter, selectedHighlights: selectedHighlights}, function(data){
                         $('.disFilter').html(data).fadeIn("2000");

                    });
            }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
         <script language="JavaScript">
                        function toggle() {
                            if($("#check-buton").prop("checked") == true){
                                $('.chkall').prop('checked', true);
                            }else{
                                $('.chkall').prop('checked', false);
                            }

                        }
    $('#industry').click(function(){
                if($('#s').val().trim())
                {
                    window.location.href= '<?php echo base_url();?>search?industry_id='+$('#industry_id').val().trim()
                }else{
                    $('#alert_error').text('Please Select Industry').show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
                    </script>

                     <div class="loginAccount">

                    <form method="post" name="search" action="<?php echo base_url();?>search">
                        <h3>Search by Industry :</h3>
                        Select All: <input type="checkbox" name="industry_id[]" id="check-buton" value="" onclick="toggle()">

                        <ul class="searchbyindustry">





                        <?php
                        if($Industries)
                        {?>
                            <?php
                        foreach($Industries as $Industry)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li>    <input type="checkbox" name="industry_id[]" class="chkall" value="<?php echo $Industry['id'];?>"> <?php echo $Industry['industry_name'];?>
                            </li> <?php
                        } }
                        ?>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
        <!--                <button type="button" id="industry">Search</button>-->
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
                        </ul>

                    </form> 
<?php 
if(_inputPost('industry_id'))
            {
                $ind=implode(',', _inputPost('industry_id'));
                //print($ind);die;
                $ind=ltrim($ind,',');
                $industry_id = $ind;
                $flag = true;
                $condition = ' and sector in ('.$ind.')';
                $extraparams = '?industry_id='.$industry_id;

            }else if(_inputGet('industry_id'))
                {
                    $ind= _inputGet('industry_id');
                    //print($ind);die;
                     $ind=ltrim($ind,',');
                    $industry_id = $ind;
                    $flag = true;
                    $condition = ' and sector in ('.$ind.')';
                    $extraparams = '?industry_id='.$industry_id;

                }
        else if(trim(_inputGet('s')))
            {
                $s = trim(_inputGet('s'));
                $flag = true;
                $condition = ' and (name LIKE '.$this->db->escape('%'.$s.'%').' or mobile_office LIKE '.$this->db->escape('%'.$s.'%').' or mobile2 LIKE '.$this->db->escape('%'.$s.'%').' or email2 LIKE '.$this->db->escape('%'.$s.'%').")";
                $extraparams = '?s='.$s;
            }
```

Comment: i dont understand all this code you posted and its relationship to my problem.